# Galois weight of a Serre twisted pure Galois representation

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, galois-representations

Let $V$ be a pure, 2-dimensional weight $k$ $p$-adic global Galois representation for $G$, the absolute Galois group of the rationals.

Let $c\in Z^1(G,\text{SL}_2)$ be a cocycle and consider the Serre twist of $V$ by $c$, that is, the representation ${}_cV$, defined via: assume $\rho: G\longrightarrow \text{GL}(V)$ is the representation associated to $V$, then the twisted representation is given by: $g\mapsto c(g)^{-1}\rho(g)c(g)$.

Then, how does the weight of ${}_cV$ change w.r.t. that of $V$ and $c$?

Any reference would also be appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have never heard of this "Serre twisting" operation before (and I have not attempted to check that your formula gives a well-defined representation, which is not obvious to me); but since the weight of a Galois representation is a condition on the *eigenvalues* of Frobenius elements, and conjugation doesn't change the eigenvalues, it is clear that if ${}_c V$ exists then it will be pure of the same weight as $V$.